# How to restore from grub my fedora boot?

Tags: fedora, grub2

I changed tomorrowto my old hdd to save some old files.
After I installed again the new disk I cannot boot anymore in fedora and I see only the grub command display. [image]
Now I have only my phone so I took a picture and I don’t know what to enter in the ‘root=‘ command as you can see on the picture. Could you help me to restore the boot process on my pc?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine based on the image you posted, you'll need:

```
linuxefi (hd0,gpt6)/vmlinuz-5.0.16-100.fc28.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap
initrd (hd0,gpt6)/initramfs-5.0.16-100.fc28.x86_64.img
boot
```

You might get more diagnostic output than you're familiar with at startup, because some non-essential options were omitted, but that should get your system up and running.

After the system is up and running: make sure `/boot/efi` is mounted, then run `grub2-install /dev/sda` to refresh the GRUB installation and the UEFI NVRAM boot variable (you can use `efibootmgr -v` to check the UEFI boot variables).

Comment: Should I use also before the command root=bla bla ? or only the 3 commands from your post are enough?